# Eclipse TableViewer Selection Event When Data Changes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm relying on the selection service in my eclipse plugin to react to selection changes in a TableViewer.

This works fine, but sometimes I change the data in the table (while the selection doesn't change).  Unfortunately, changing the data in the table doesn't trigger this event.  I tried manually setting the selection to the first item after doing this:

```
//Update the table here

if(viewer.getTable().getItemCount() > 0){

 viewer.getTable().setSelection(0);
}
```

This does not cause a selection change event, even though the selection does change.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the data in your model you can tell the `TableViewer` to update from the model using:

```
viewer.update(element, null);
```

where 'element' is the model element that you have changed.

Generally when using `TableViewer` you should avoid accessing the underlying `Table`.